# Aurelia-CLI generated project file structure - where to place css and images?

Tags: aurelia

Generating a new project using aurelia-cli with the following options:

```
Name: test-project
Platform: Web
Bundler: Aurelia-CLI
Loader: SystemJS
Transpiler: Babel
Markup Processor: Minimal Minification
CSS Processor: None
Unit Test Runner: None
Integration Test Runner: None
Editor: None
```

Produces this file structure:

```
test-project
    ...
    ...
    src
        resources
        app.js
        app.html
        main.js
        ...
    index.html
    favicon.ico
    ...
```

I am wondering where you should place images and CSS files? At the moment I have the following:

```
test-project
    ...
    ...
    images
        img-1.png
        img-2.png
        ...
    src
        resources
        app.js
        app.html
        app.css
        main.js
        ...
    index.html
    favicon.ico
    ...
```

Comment: This is a primarily opinion based question. My opinion is to place them how you currently have them, but there are others who would disagree with me.

Comment: i get a `static` folder generated too (in parallel to `src` folder). I use this folder.